# Regex for alphanumeric with only one space or one hypen

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regular-language

I need a regular expression which needs to satisfy the following :-

1. It should accepts alphanumeric
2. only one `space` OR `hyphen` Or both can be there. But in any case it should be only one `space` or one `hyphen`
3. Max Total length should be 10 characters

For example valid data

- W1A 1HQ
- 1234-456
- IT-12345
- 12345

So far I have tried with below expression but it is not working properly

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9][^\s\-].*[^\s\-][a-zA-Z0-9]){0,8}
```

Do I need to modify anything here ?

**Edit**
The solution posted here doesn't accept the combination of one space and one hypen within String.
Please provide an expression that will support all the requirement together in combinations.

Comment: Yes, you do. `A1.B2.C3.D4.E5` is valid, according to your current RegExp.

Comment: `(?=.*{0,10})[a-z0-9]+(?:[-\s][a-z0-9]+)?`

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary Posting "*The solution posted here doesn't accept ...*" is an understatement, specially for someone with 2k+ rep. Don't you think you should provide a test case as well as the code you're using? I believe you're currently having a problem with your code, not the regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex `/^(?=.{0,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][a-z0-9]+)?$/i`

**DEMO :**

```js
$('#input').on('input', function() {
  $('#res').text(this.value.match(/^(?=.{0,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][a-z0-9]+)?$/i) ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
<div id="res"></div>
```

**[Explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/rR1hS0/1)**

```
^(?=.{0,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][a-z0-9]+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

**UPDATE :**

> only one space OR hyphen Or both can be there

**[`/^(?=.{0,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:([\s-])[a-z0-9]*(?:(?!\1)[\s-])?[a-z0-9]+)?$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/uA2wI9/2)**

```js
$('#input').on('input', function() {
  $('#res').text(this.value.match(/^(?=.{0,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:([\s-])[a-z0-9]*(?:(?!\1)[\s-])?[a-z0-9]+)?$/i) ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
<div id="res"></div>
```

```
^(?=.{0,10}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:([\s-])[a-z0-9]*(?:(?!\1)[\s-])?[a-z0-9]+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Did you draw the graphs yourself, or is there some website where this is done automatically? This is really great visual help for us who are still struggling with regex :D

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary : can you elaborate your problem

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary : in which case problem occuring

Answer (score 2):

This expression also validates:

> only one `space` OR `hyphen` Or **both can be there**

and allows hyphens/spaces at the beggining or end of the string.

**Regex**

```
/^(?!(?:[^-]*-){2}|(?:[^ ]* ){2})[- a-z0-9]{0,10}$/i
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7nG4/1)</kbd>

It matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(?:[^-]*-){2}|(?:[^ ]* ){2})` Not followed by:  ([negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

  - `(?:[^-]*-){2})` 2 hyphens, or
  - `(?:[^ ]* ){2}` 2 spaces
- `[- a-z0-9]{0,10}` alphanumerics, hyphens or spaces, with max length of 10
- `$` End of string
- Mode `/i`: case insensitive match

---

**Code**

```js
str = "-ABC 123";
re = /^(?!(?:[^-]*-){2}|(?:[^ ]* ){2})[- a-z0-9]{0,10}$/i;

if (str.match(re)) {
  document.body.innerText += "VALID";
} else {
  document.body.innerText += "Invalid string";
}
```

Comment: The solution posted here doesn't accept the combination of one space and one hypen within String. Please provide an expression that will support all the requirement together in combinations.

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary It does match `str -ing`. In fact, the example in the code snippet actually has 1 hyphen and 1 space. Can you provide an example where it would fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?=.{1,10}$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*\-{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

Detailed explanation is available here: https://regex101.com/r/hV3rJ2/1

Comment: Give some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: The solution posted here doesn't accept the combination of one space and one hypen within String. Please provide an expression that will support all the requirement together in combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parameter: String which has to be checked with a
//   regular Expression.

function checkString(toCheck) {

  if (toCheck.length <= 10) {
    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s|-|\s-|-\s)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

    if (reg.test(toCheck)) {
      return true;
    } 
  } 

 return false;
}
```

Complete example on codepen: 
http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/EVMRJG

Comment: The solution posted here doesn't accept the combination of one space and one hypen within String. Please provide an expression that will support all the requirement together in combinations.

Comment: ( ... \s-|-\s ...)  => Means: Space followed by a hyphen OR hypen followed by a space. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Please have a look at the codepen example: http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/EVMRJG - I've added two additional values '123 -abc', '123- abc'. Your gonna see it works.